# Resizing an SKSpriteNode without losing quality

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3

I have an SKSpiteNode:

```
private var btnSound = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "btnSound")
```

Now I made this image in Adobe Illustrator with a size of 2048x2048 pixels (overkill really), so it has good resolution. My problem is when I set the size of it the image, the lines in it go serrated or jagged...not smooth.

This is how I size it:

```
        btnSound.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width * 1 / 5 , y: self.frame.height * (5.2 / 8))
        btnSound.size.width = self.frame.width * 1 / 7
        btnSound.size.height = btnSound.size.width
        btnSound.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(btnSound)
```

This is the image when in Illustrator (screenshot)[image]and this is the image in the app (screenshot) [image]

Things I have tried:

- Making the image PDF
- Making the image PNG
- Making the PNG 72 DPI, making it 300 DPI
- Run on simulator / device (iPhone7)
- `btnSound.setScale(preDetermineScale)`
- Using the following function, though I am not familiar with the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext method. The image just comes out blurry with this. Heres the code and the resulting image:

  ```
  func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

  let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
  let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
  image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))

  let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

  return newImage
  }

  func setup() {
  let btnSoundImg = UIImage(named: "btnSound")
  let resizeBtnSoundImage = resizeImage(image: btnSoundImg!, newWidth: self.frame.width * 1 / 7)
  let btnSoundTexture = SKTexture(image: resizeBtnSoundImage!)

  btnSound.texture = btnSoundTexture
  btnSound.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width * 1 / 5 , y: self.frame.height * (5.2 / 8))
  btnSound.size.width = self.frame.width * 1 / 7
  btnSound.size.height = btnSound.size.width
  btnSound.zPosition = 1
  self.addChild(btnSound)
  }
  ```

[image: blurry image]

I am self taught and haven't done a whole lot of programming so I'd love to learn how to do this correctly as I'm only finding solutions for resizing UIImageViews.

Another thought I had was maybe it shouldn't be a spriteNode as its just used for a button?

Comment: Why don't you just make your image in the size that it will be in your app?

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it. I just make them big so if I need them later in a higher resolution I can adjust them. Also, they will vary depending on device type.

Comment: What extension btnSound image has (the one added to your project)? Also, I would advise to stick to sprites in SpriteKit. Using UIKit elements will require some additional  work , eg. when transitioning to another scene you will have to manually remove UIKit elements, becuase those are added to the view, and not to the scene (unlike nodes which are part of a node tree).

Comment: Also if your image is not a vector, but rather bitmap, having that large image (2048x2048) and then downscaling it,  is just wasting of resources.

Comment: An image like that can probably be done in vector gfx which apple technically supports. (It will render the png at compile time)

Answer (score 11):

First up, there's some primitive rules to follow, to get the best results.

1. Only scale by factors of 2. ie 50%, 25%, 12.5% 6.25% etc.

   This way, any four pixels in your original image become 1 pixel in your scaled image, for each step down in scale size.
2. Make your original image a square of an exponent of 2 in size. So: 128x128, 256x256, 512x512, etc. You've covered this already with your 2048x2048 sizing.
3. Turn on mipmapping. This is off, by default, in SpriteKit, so you have to switch it on: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sktexture/1519960-usesmipmaps
4. Play with the different filtering modes to get the best reductions of noise and banding in your image: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sktexture/1519659-filteringmode  hint, linear will probably be better.
5. As has always been the case, judicious use of Photoshop for manually scaling will give you the best results and least flexibility

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I was having a look at the mipmapping but have not used it before. Would you be able to give an example about how it works or is it a bit too involved for this particular question?